# How can I modify the "Picture Styles" shortcut gallery in Microsoft Office (Word and Powerpoint, specifically)?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

The Microsoft Office Ribbon has a convenient gallery of styles to apply to pictures, shown here:

[image]

It functions much like the Quick Styles gallery in Word for quickly applying formatting to text. But whereas one can create a new text style and add it to the Quick Styles gallery, I haven't been able to find a way to do the same with the Picture Styles gallery. The default styles aren't what I need, and the styles I do need involve changing multiple settings, so a shortcut would be nice. Am I stuck just using the copy-paste format options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the short answer is no, Microsoft Word doesn't allow you to create or edit picture styles.

However I did find a very nice work around [here](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/small-business/3375289/10-microsoft-word-style-secrets/), here's a formatted version of what it says:

---

> Microsoft Word 2010 provides no means of creating a style for a picture that you can use to quickly format all of your images in the future. However, you have a workaround involving Quick Parts:
>
> **Format an Image**
>
> 1. Add an image to your document by clicking *Insert* -> *Picture*
> 2. Choose a picture in the dialog box.
> 3. Click the picture, select the *Picture Tools* tab, and choose *Format*.
>
> At this point you can adjust how the text should wrap around the picture, indicate whether the text appears on top of the picture, customize a border for the picture, or what have you.
>
> Once you've applied formatting to your satisfaction:
>
> **Create a Quick Part**
>
> 1. click the image to select it
> 2. Choose *Insert* -> *Quick Parts* -> *Save Selection to Quick Part Gallery*.
> 3. Type a name for the image, and choose to save it to the Quick Parts Gallery.
> 4. Save it in your Building Blocks.dotx file.
> 5. click *OK*.
>
> In the future, you can add this formatted image to a file like this:
>
> **Apply Quick Part to a new Image**
>
> 1. *Insert* -> *Quick Parts* and click the image.
> 2. Right-click the image.
> 3. Choose *Change Picture* and select the new image.
>
> The new image will appear in the existing border, thus saving you from having to reproduce the border (and other formatting) each and every time you add a picture to your document.

Comment: This is a [Rube Goldbeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) way of applying formatting. A shortcut is to **format one image** the way you want it, **insert a new image**, **click the first image**, **click the paint brush tool** (copies formatting), **click the new image** (pastes formatting onto the new image). You can also accomplish the copy/paste formatting functionality with `Ctrl+Shift+C`/`Ctrl+Shift+V`. Actually, I'll just post an answer.

Comment: No, it's a work around to add a feature that should've been present to start with. If you read closely the OP already knows about and suggests copy formatting which is not what he really wants. Your method does not add the style to a gallery for easy reuse down the line as the OP implied he wanted to have.

Comment: OK, it just seems like the overall structure of the instructions are: `1. insert a pic 2. format it 3. Copy/Paste it 4. Replace it with another image so the formatting sticks` which seems like the exact same thing as format painting. Also, I don't think Quick Parts is in later versions of word. Perhaps they changed it to "Styles"? However, styles doesn't seem to work completely for images.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there is no way to apply formatting on insertion, but there's way easier ways to apply formatting:

1. Insert a picture, format it
2. Insert a new picture
3. Click the first picture
4. **Ctrl+Shift+C**
5. Click the new image
6. **Ctrl+Shift+V**

This has similar functionality to the Format Painter tool:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building off the suggestion by [Adam](https://superuser.com/users/143982/adam), I came up with a simpler solution if you'd like to use the style on multiple images (which is what I like the Quick Styles gallery for). Follow these instructions from [Adam](https://superuser.com/users/143982/adam)'s answer to create a Quick Part with the formatting you'd like:

1. Add an image to your document by clicking Insert > Picture and then choosing a picture in the dialog box.
2. Next, click the picture, select the Picture Tools tab, and choose Format.
3. At this point you can adjust how the text should wrap around the picture, indicate whether the text appears on top of the picture, customize a border for the picture, or what have you.
4. Once you've applied formatting to your satisfaction, click the image to select it and choose Insert > Quick Parts > Save Selection to Quick Part Gallery. Type a name for the image, and choose to save it to the Quick Parts Gallery. Save it in your Building Blocks.dotx file, and click OK.

Instead of inserting the image from Quick Parts and swapping the image with the one you'd like to use for each image in your document, instead,

5. Insert the quickpart image one time.
6. Highlight it, and press Ctrl+Shift+C to copy the formatting.
7. Highlight the image you'd like to apply the style to, and press Ctrl+Shift+V

Comment: Nice improvement!

Answer (score 1):

**Formatting pictures in 3 clicks of your Quick Access Toolbar...**

I understand this is an old post... but it is still applicable due to Office 365's shortcomings.

This solution is designed to apply your predefined custom picture format on a new image pasted from the clipboard. (But if you're a savvy Office user, which you are because you are reading this, you can tweak this apporach to your preference.)

Once this approach is set up, it only involves 3 clicks on the Quick Access Toolbar to format your pictures. All the clicks take place in a very small area of your screen - much more efficient than navigating through the tabs and options in the ribbons.

**INITIAL SETUP PART 1:** *Defining your Picture Format*

1. Insert a picture into your document or email. Format it as to your liking. Select the picture.
2. From the *Insert* tab, click *Quick Parts*, and click *Save Selection to Quick Part Gallery*

**INITIAL SETUP PART 2:** *Config your Toolbar*

3. From the *Insert* tab, click *Quick Parts*, and right-click your Quick Part
4. Click *Add Gallery to Quick Access Toolbar*
5. Making sure your picture is selected, click on the *Format* tab
6. Click on Change Picture, then right-click on *From Clipboard*
7. Click *Add Gallery to Quick Access Toolbar*

Now that you are setup, you can format your new pictures in 2 clicks.... In this case, have your picture on your clipboard, ready to be pasted into your document or email.

1. Click the QAT button you added from step 2... your Quick Part gallery will appear; Click on your Quick Part. This adds your predefined formatted picture into your document. Select the picture (I admit I didn't count this as one of the clicks!)
2. Click the QAT button you added in step 7. Voila! Your new image now resides in your document with your custom formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I have a faster option than even that. Use the "Format Painter". It works on images as well.

Format your original image as you like. Select the image. If you single click the format painter (on the home ribbon, usually under the Cut and Copy buttons), you can "paint" the format onto one image elsewhere in the document. If you double click the format painter, it will "hold" the style and you can select multiple images one at a time to format them. I think that's still faster than either of your options.